# Poor response from iPad screen in web app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ipad, ios6, dom-events

I have a web app. Part of it running on iPad. When devices was upgraded to iOS 6, screen response getting poor and long (often, don't get response at all - our Javascript buttons didn't click). Is there a way to change screen response or anything else? (Browsers: Safari, Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Just use "ontouchend" event against "onclick" in javascript for controls.